# Using SDL2 with CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

After hours of scouring the web and SO for a solution I'm at a standstill. Nothing has worked so far for me...

I'm on Windows, using CLion IDE which uses CMake. My goal is to correctly link `SDL2` to my project and use it through `#include "SDL.h"` which is the correct way.

- The format of my `CMakeLists.txt` file
- Specifics regarding the directory where I should have put the `MingW development library` of SDL2
- Any requirements regarding windows ENV variables that I might have to set.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(sdl2Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
#This is where sdl2-config.cmake is located
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/cmake/SDL2")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(sdl2Project ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(sdl2 REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(sdl2Project PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(sdl2Project ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

There is no `FindSDL2.cmake` file used.

The `SDL2` library I downloaded from `libsdl.org` is located in:
`C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32`

I have no experience with CMake so I'm unable to truly understand where the problem stems from. What are the steps I need to take in order for it to find the library and link it correctly??

**EDIT:**

My Project structure is the following:

```
sdl2Project
  cmake-build-debug
  CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking in your [`FindSDL2.cmake`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendan-w/collector/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake), you need to provide an hint to CMake about where the library is installed. You could do this by setting an environment variable `SDLDIR`, but you shouldn't. General advice: you shouldn't use a CMake package that wasn't provided with the sources you're using.

Looking in [sources of `SDL2`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/66c0c39a4e19), root directory contains a file `sdl2-config.cmake.in` that should have been configured and installed in your install directory as `sdl2-config.cmake`: that's the package file you should use.

Am I right guessing the file `C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5/sdl2-config.cmake` exists?

If yes, to allow CMake to find it, add your install directory to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, before calling `find_package`:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    "C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5"
)

find_package(sdl2 REQUIRED)
```

Note the use of "/" in the path instead of "\" which could be interpreted as escaping character. Quotes around the path are only necessary if the path contains whitespaces.

**EDIT:**

Moreover, you misused `target_link_libraries` with a wrong target: `SDL2` which you don't build in your project, instead of `sdl2Project`.

You also used a wrong variable: `SDL2_LIBRARY` instead of `SDL2_LIBRARIES`; you can see the good variable name by looking in `sdl2-config.cmake`.

You may consider `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`, but again the variable name you used is wrong: `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR` instead of `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

Try:

```
target_include_directories(sdl2Project PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(sdl2Project ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: There is a `sdl2-config.cmake` under:

`C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/cmake/SDL2`

Comment: Then use it with my proposed solution ;)

Comment: It gives me the following error:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "SDL2" which is not built by this
  project.`

Note: Line 18 is the `target_link_libraries` command

Comment: I didn't pay attention to your cmake project, but you have some issues detailed in my edit. Not sure, but I think you should also use `find_package(sdl2 ...` instead of `find_package(SDL2 ...` since `sdl2-config.cmake` uses lowercase for `sdl2` in its file name

Comment: @Konstantine Use `target_link_libraries(sdl2Project ${SDL2_LIBRARY})` instead.

Comment: Damn it worked but I'm not sure which changes triggered it. Although after some testing, I think the problem is what @Shmuel H. said:

`target_link_libraries(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME ${SDL2_LIBRARY})`

is the correct syntax

Comment: @Konstantine that's not the only issue, see my edited answer

Comment: If you check the `FindSDL2.cmake` you'll see that it uses `SDL2_LIBRARY` and not `LIBRARIES`.

After remaking the project from scratch, only 2 changes were needed:
1. Adding the `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:/Users/KPentaris/C Projects/Libraries/SDL2-2.0.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32")`
2. Changing the project name in `target_link_libraries` from `SDL2` to `sdl2Project` (or whatever your project name is).

Comment: You missed a point here :) You should **not** use your `FindSDL2.cmake`: remove it, clean your build directory, make the appropriate changes and configure again. `FindSDL2.cmake` may work today, but you're only lucky here: you can't be sure it will work later when you will change your version of SDL, even for a minor version. You should use the package provided with the sources. And `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should be filled with `C:/Users/MyUserName/CLibraries/SDL2-2.0.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32‌​/lib/cmake/SDL2`

Comment: Ugh now it started failing again. It doesn't seem to be able to detect the include directories. Note that I changed the path given in the `sdl2-config.cmake` to target my own library's path. I updated my question with new files